# Open Office Calc: Convert a date to timestamp

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, date, timestamp

I have a column with dates in M/D/Y like this:

```
8/8/2007
8/9/2007
8/10/2007
8/13/2007
8/14/2007
8/15/2007
8/16/2007
```

I would like to convert them to a unix timestamp (in a new column). Would anyone know how I can do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've actually figured this one out, here is the answer:

=(C2 - DATEVALUE("1/1/1970"))*86400

Comment: Thanks for this. Calc should have a an EPOCH() function for this =)

Comment: I don't see EPOCH in Libreoffice